# Interfacing Expression<Func<T, bool>> gives "cannot resolve symbol Language"

Tags: c#, lambda, compiler-errors, mocking, expression

I have some code that I am refactoring to depend on interfaces so that I can inject the dependancies and unit test/mock the dependancies.

The original code looked like this when simplified:

```
private Expression<Func<SearchResultItem, bool>> AddFilterByLanguage(Expression<Func<SearchResultItem, bool>> query)
{
        Expression<Func<SearchResultItem, bool>> languageQuery = PredicateBuilder.False<SearchResultItem>();

        languageQuery = languageQuery.Or(i => i.Language == _searchParams.ContextLanguage);

        return query.And(languageQuery);
}
```

To unit test this code my plan is to add use fake implementations of the PredicateBuilder and Expression so that I can build a dummy query and verify that the relevant parts were called correctly.

So I have replaced PredicateBuilder with an injected IPredicateBuilder that returns IExpressions instead as defined below.

```
public interface IPredicateBuilder
{
    IExpression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>();
    IExpression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>();
}

public interface IExpression<T> 
{
    IExpression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(IExpression<Func<T, bool>> func);
    IExpression<Func<T, bool>> Or(IExpression<Func<T, bool>> func);
}
```

And the changed code now looks like this:

```
private IExpression<Func<SearchResultItem, bool>> AddFilterByLanguage(Expression<Func<SearchResultItem, bool>> query)
{
        IExpression<Func<SearchResultItem, bool>> languageQuery = _predicateBuilder.False<SearchResultItem>();

        languageQuery = languageQuery.Or(i => i.Language == _searchParams.ContextLanguage);

        return query.And(languageQuery);
}
```

Where

```
private readonly IPredicateBuilder _predicateBuilder;
```

My problem is that I get a "cannot resolve symbol Language" on this line:

```
languageQuery = languageQuery.Or(i => i.Language == _searchParams.ContextLanguage);
```

Any suggestion as to how best to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: I really wouldn't start using mocking for this - that doesn't sound like a good idea to me. You can easily check whether the relevant pieces get called with the *normal* `PredicateBulder`. I don't think your `And` method should be generic, either.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jon. I did consider this but thought that actually I'd be executing more code in my unit test than I actually need too. It would start to look a bit more like integration testing as I'd be essentially testing more that a single class's functionality. PredicateBuilder in this case lives in the Sitecore namespace and I'd like to leave that out of the unit tests. 

Not sure writing more code (ie the fakes) helps though.

Comment: Compiler knows how to generate proper code that will create an `Expression` out of lambda expression. However, it doesn't know how to generate `IExpression` from the same lambda expression.

Comment: Do you mock every collection you use as well? Do you try to mock strings? Mock what needs to be mocked - but don't go over the top. It's useful if you can provide some sort of local data to filter on, in order to make the tests faster - but I'm sure `PredicateBuilder` will work with a `List<T>` using `AsQueryable`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Indeed, the parameters to `And` and `Or` should probably be `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` - but as I say, I wouldn't do this at all.

Comment: So just run the code against PredicateBuilder, get Expressions back then query that the expression has been built correctly somehow in the unit test. Is that what you mean. I'll look into how to compare the Expression against what is the expected one in the Assert of the unit test. Thanks